# before:18 years ago Laravel validator message not working

Tags: php, laravel, pyrocms

I'm very new to Laravel. So please go easy on me.

I'm having this message for "before:18 years ago" date validator.

```
The "" must be a date before 18 years ago.
```

How can I customize it ? Do I need to compile something ?

I have this in my validation.php which is in the resources/lang/en/

```
'custom' => [
    'dob' => [
        'before' => 'Invalid Age'
    ],
 ],
```

I'm using a FormBuilder

https://pyrocms.com/help/developer-tools/form-builders/creating-a-form-builder

```
'dob' => [
        'type'   => 'anomaly.field_type.datetime',
        'config' => [
            "mode"          => "date",
            "date_format"   => "j F, Y",
             "year_range"    => "-100:-18",
             ],
        'rules'  => [
            'required','before:18 years ago' 
         ],

       ],
```

Comment: Where do you perform the validation? Show us the validator code.

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize validation messages by specifying attributes within the message text:

```
$messages = [
    'dob' => 'The :attribute must be a date before 18 years ago.',
];
```

When passed to a validator instance the `:attribute` placeholder will be substituted.

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Using language files, you define the message text the same:

```
'custom' => [
   'dob' => [
       'before' => 'The :attribute must be a date before 18 years ago.'
   ],
],
```

and then optionally give the attribute a custom name:

```
'attributes' => [
    'dob' => 'date of birth',
],
```

> You may retrieve lines from language files using the __ helper function. The __ method accepts the file and key of the translation string as its first argument.

[Custom Validation Error Messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-error-messages)

[Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#retrieving-translation-strings)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as the following

> In FormBuilder

```
'dob' => [
    'type'   => 'anomaly.field_type.datetime',
    'rules'  => ['required', 'older_than'],
    'config' => [
        'mode'        => 'date',
        'date_format' => 'j F, Y',
        'year_range'  => '-100:-18',
    ],
],
```

> In app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend(
        'older_than',
        function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $minAge = (!empty($parameters)) 
                ? (int) $parameters[0] 
                : 18;

            return (new DateTime)->diff(new DateTime($value))->y >= $minAge;
        }
    );

    Validator::replacer(
        'older_than',
        function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
            return "The age must be at least {$parameters[0]}";
        }
    );
}
```